# :target behaviour but on :hover in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

#### Consider the [w3schools example of the `:target` selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_target):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
:target {
    border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p><a href="#news1">Jump to New content 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#news2">Jump to New content 2</a></p>

<p>Click on the links above and the :target selector highlight the current active HTML anchor.</p>

<p id="news1"><b>New content 1...</b></p>
<p id="news2"><b>New content 2...</b></p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :target selector.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

When you click on the `a`nchor referencing another element it styles the`p` with the corresponding `id`.

#### I want the effect of :target but on *hover* instead. how is this done?

how do you style the thing that `href` points to in the page on hover?

#### *if this is not possible. what is the best-performing javascript solution?*

Comment: Unless the target is a later sibling, descendant, or descendant of a later sibling, you can't, without JavaScript. Though the [reference combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#idref-combinators), from CSS selectors level 4 API may allow this.

Comment: @DavidThomas in real case I can only predict that the thing I want to target on hover has the id i'm href'ing. What is the simplest way to accomplish this with javascript?

Comment: @David Thomas: The reference combinator has been gone for quite a while. That WD is already 2 years old and needs to be updated, or pulled, stat.

Comment: @BoltClock: my ability to accurately - or, sometimes, even *adequately* - search the W3C's working drafts appears to be limited, do you have a link to the most-current version, or to the source that details the removal of the reference combinator? I don't doubt you, but I'm a little sad to see it being dropped; it seemed potentially useful (albeit a little unpredictable/unclear in its syntax).

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4 One directory up and you'll find a collection of the latest editors' drafts. Less stable, but more current, just like nightly builds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because CSS selectors can only traverse from an earlier element to a later sibling, descendant or descendant of a sibling (and cannot select parent, or previous-sibling, elements), this cannot be done with CSS. As hovering the `<a>` to style the later `:target`-ed elements would first require traversing to the parent from the hovered-`<a>` element.

To do this with JavaScript, then, I'd suggest:

```js
// a named function to toggle the highlighting of the
// targeted element:
function highlightTarget(event) {
  // the 'event' is passed automagically from the
  // addEventListener() method; as is the 'this'
  // which is the element to which the event-handler
  // (this function) was bound:

  // using getAttribute() to get the value of the attribute,
  // instead of 'this.href' which would get the absolute URL,
  // replacing the leading '#' character with an empty string:
  var id = this.getAttribute('href').replace(/^#/, ''),
    // getting the element with that id:
    target = document.getElementById(id);

  switch (event.type) {
    // if this is the mouseenter event we add the 'highlight'
    // class-name:
    case 'mouseenter':
      target.classList.add('highlight');
      break;
    // on 'mouseleave' we remove the class-name:
    case 'mouseleave':
      target.classList.remove('highlight');
      break;
  }
}

// iterating over the NodeList returned by
// document.getElementsByTagName(), using
// Array.prototype.forEach():
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function(a) {
  // if the href attribute (not property) begins with a '#':
  if (a.getAttribute('href').indexOf('#') === 0) {
    // we bind the highlightTarget function to handle
    // both the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events:
    a.addEventListener('mouseenter', highlightTarget);
    a.addEventListener('mouseleave', highlightTarget);
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p><a href="#news1">Jump to New content 1</a>
</p>
<p><a href="#news2">Jump to New content 2</a>
</p>

<p>Click on the links above and the :target selector highlight the current active HTML anchor.</p>

<p id="news1"><b>New content 1...</b>
</p>
<p id="news2"><b>New content 2...</b>
</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :target selector.</p>
```

It is worth noting, though, that the CSS Selectors Module, Level 4, has a proposed solution, the reference-combinator, to address this:

> The following example highlights an  element when its  is focused or hovered-over:

```
    label:matches(:hover, :focus) /for/ input,       /* association by "for" attribute */
    label:matches(:hover, :focus):not([for]) input { /* association by containment */
        box-shadow: yellow 0 0 10px; 
    }
```

Which suggests that the correct syntax (which, currently of course, does not work) may be:

```
a:matches(:hover) /href/ p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Reference combinator (`E:matches(:hover) /href/ p`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#idref-combinators).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [Guide to JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
  - [`switch () {...}` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: @DavidThomas  accept for greatly-explained solution and +1 for reference combinator... !

Answer (score 4):

For Info:

In CSS if link is ahead and adjacent to the target or target's parent, then you could do something similar:

```css
[href="#news1"]:hover ~#news1,
[href="#news2"]:hover ~#news2{
    border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<a href="#news1">Jump to New content 1</a>
<a href="#news2">Jump to New content 2</a>

<p>hover link and see target element highlight via <code>[href="#target] ~#target </code></p>

<p id="news1"><b>New content 1...</b></p>
<p id="news2"><b>New content 2...</b></p>

<p><b>Note:</b> links must be ahead and adjacent to target or parents target in order to work.</p>
```

---

To go further and understand ,See: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation
and notice those too  : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators & http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators

---

Comment: @Harry, right , i'll fix this, apologies for my average english ;)